# DOMXPath/PHP - Get a value only after specific occurrence

Tags: php, xml, json, algorithm, domxpath

Guys I'm parsing an URL to get HTML dom elements.

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
$url = 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/nike-satire-mens-skate-shoes-242188?colcode=24218822';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument; 

$dom->loadHTMLFile($url); 

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$qry = '//script[starts-with(normalize-space(.), "var colourVariantsInitialData")]';

$rawtxt = $xp->query($qry)->item(0)->nodeValue;


$jsonStart = strpos($rawtxt, '[');
$jsonEnd = strrpos($rawtxt, ']');

$collections = json_decode(substr($rawtxt, $jsonStart, $jsonEnd - $jsonStart + 1));

foreach ($collections[1]->SizeVariants as $item) {
    $SizeName = $item->SizeName;
    $PriceUnformated = $item->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice;

    $find = array('£');
    $replace   = array('');
    $Price = str_replace($find, $replace, $PriceUnformated);

    echo "SizeName: <b>$SizeName</b> - Price: <b>$Price</b><br>";

}
```

This code is fetching "text" from a script from the output source.
Here is the complete text from this script: http://pastebin.com/FwK9Z8CP

My code is giving the following result:

```
SizeName: 7 (41) - Price: 27.00
SizeName: 8 (42.5) - Price: 36.00
SizeName: 9 (44) - Price: 36.00
SizeName: 9.5 (44.5) - Price: 36.00
SizeName: 11 (46) - Price: 36.00
```

**My question is:**

How I can get only the result for a specific SizeName, for example let's say for SizeName 7 (41) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$specific` have the string that you want find. Change the `foreach` in your code to this:

```
$specific = '7 (41)';

foreach ($collections[1]->SizeVariants as $item) {
    $SizeName = $item->SizeName;

if(trim($SizeName) == trim($specific)) {

    $PriceUnformated = $item->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice;

    $find = array('£');
    $replace   = array('');
    $Price = str_replace($find, $replace, $PriceUnformated);

    echo "SizeName: <b>$SizeName</b> - Price: <b>$Price</b><br>";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adrian, can we use `preg_quote($specific)`, so we can skip the part where we have to remove the symbols like `(` ?

Comment: @TonyStark if you only want the price, check the answer now, or tell me what output you expect

Comment: No no, it's cool! But can you please check again my updated comment ?

Comment: Can we use `preg_quote` so we can escape the special symbols ?

Comment: @TonyStark but if you use preg_quote is more dificult to get the ID, the answer don't solve your question?

Comment: No it's not, because in the example the special symbol is `(` but in other cases the special symbol can be another and this will brake the functionality.

Comment: There are cases where the SizeName will be for example `XXL` so this code will take only the first letter like `X` which is not a working solution. Oher example is `Kid's size`. As you can see there can be a lot of cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74213/discussion-between-adrian-cid-almaguer-and-tony-stark).

Comment: @TonyStark I edit, just put in specific the value that you want, go to chat to talk more about this

Comment: I used your code, but changed it alot to make it work on the way i need. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> How I can get only the result for a specific SizeName, for example let's say for SizeName 7 (41) ?

As the text as a whole is part of the XML document, you can't with the XML parser.

So technically this is not an xpath question.

You already parse the string as JSON and you're successful with that. But you still are not confident enought.

You can therefore develop a data-model that works on top of the JSON data and then implement a filter on it. A simple model could be done with an **Interator** to traverse the items and the a **FilterIterator** to pick only those with specific property values.

```
...

$xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query  = '//script[starts-with(normalize-space(.), "var colourVariantsInitialData")]';
$script = $xpath->query($query)->item(0)->nodeValue;

$variants = SizeVariants::create($script); # Iterator
$variants = new SizeFilter($variants); # FilterIterator

foreach ($variants as $item) {
    $SizeName        = $item->SizeName;
    $PriceUnformated = $item->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice;

    $find    = array('£');
    $replace = array('');
    $Price   = str_replace($find, $replace, $PriceUnformated);

    echo "SizeName: **$SizeName** - Price: **$Price**\n";
}
```

Exemplary output (markdown):

> SizeName: **7 (41)** - Price: **27.00**

And [the example code](https://gist.github.com/hakre/c14387750698bc6cd723).